# How do I count the related previous results of a VLOOKUP and add the next sequential number to the VLOOKUP's result?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet of actions (Corrective, NCR, IMP, etc.), and need to have it automatically count the previous actions raised of the same type in order to create unique action IDs.

I have used `VLOOKUP()` to get the first part of the action ID (the type), but I can't work out how to get it to count the actions of the same type in that column to get the next-sequential-number part.

So far I have the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet3!A2:B5,2)
```

This works to identify the type, i.e. `CAR`, `OBS`, `IMP`, and `NCR`.

Can anyone help with how to add the sequential number part?

EDIT:

I want the result of the formula to give each action of the same type a unique ID. So, for example, if there are multiple actions of type `NCR` it will generate the IDs like this: `NCR0001`, `NCR0002`, `CAR0001`, `OBS0001`, `NCR0003`.

Comment: This is pretty abstract as a word description.  None of the terms mean anything to anyone else, and it isn't clear how they're represented in your spreadsheet, what your formulas point to, etc.  It would be easier for people to answer if there was something to look at.  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I tried to but it won't let me as I am new member

Comment: Just post a link to the image(s) at a public sharing site (imgur.com is free and that's what this site uses).  Someone here with sufficient rep will add it for you.

Comment: Are you trying to count occurrence that the `Vlookup` formula has searched ?  Like 4 Cars or 10 OBS !!

Comment: BTW, VLOOKUP returns one result, so can you clarify what you want to count?

Comment: Rajesh I want the VLookup to give them each a unique number so when it picks up an NCR it will number like so:the first one NCR0001,  NCR0002, CAR0001, OBS0001, NCR0003

Comment: This is really too ambiguous and undefined for people to answer without seeing a sample of what the sheet looks like and what you want the output from that sheet to look like.  I'm having trouble even relating what you describe to VLOOKUP.  People will waste time developing solutions that aren't what you need.  I've voted to close, but will be happy to retract it if you turn this into a clear question.

Comment: OK Fixer1234 please close it, I will be able to do what I need using a concatenate formula

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple once you realise that the `COUNTIF()` function can be used with wildcards.

Set up `Sheet3` like this

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

and your working sheet like this

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `D3` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down/auto-fill into the rest of the table's column:

```dart
=VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet3!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)
&RIGHT(10001+COUNTIF(D$2:D2,VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet3!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)&"????"),4)
```

---

**Explanation:**

Basically the formula counts the number of actions of the same type that occur above the current cell and then creates an ID with a number part that is one more than that.

It uses the wildcard `?` (any single character) in the `COUNTIF()` function to match the current type followed by any four characters, e.g. for `D3` the function partially evaluates to `COUNTIF(D$2:D2,"NCR????")`. The key thing to note here is that `D$2:D2` is a *dynamic* range which evaluates as "from row `2` to the row above the current cell (of column `D`)".

Then `RIGHT(10001+<count of type>,4)` adds one and left-pads the number with zeroes.

Finally, this number is appended to the type.

**Notes:**

Your `VLOOKUP()` was modified to work correctly:

- The second argument needs to be an absolute address
- The fourth needs to be `FALSE` and not the default, which is `TRUE`.